# What are the steps needed for accessing a WCF service from a non .NET clients(ex.JAVA,HTML5)?

Tags: java, android, wcf, html

I want to create a WCF service which is to be accessed by a non .NET client. Apart from REST based methodology is there any steps involved in exposing the service to other client like JAVA,HTML5,Android etc., Help me out.

Comment: i want to know the steps for consuming via non .NET clients..

Answer (score 2):

Consuming a WCF Service from non .NET clients should be the same as consuming it from a .NET Client. You would need the wsdl to generate a client side proxy and use the proxy to access the WCF Service.

The WCF Service might have various security features for securing it and your client needs to adher to them to get a proper access and response back from the service.

Few things you might encounter when accessing from non .NET Clients is that the WCF service doesnt have a Flat Wsdl. In such cases it becomes a bit difficult to access it. If you are planning to develop a WCF Service for non .NET Clients i would suggest you to make sure that you have Flat Wsdl. Also it would be better off to adher to Basic Profile 1.1 for your WCF service to be interoperable and try using BasicHttpBinding to avoid many road blocks when accessing from non .NET Clients (saying that make sure your service is properly secured)

Flat Wsdl -> It means that your Wsdl should not have any import elements in it to reference external xsd's etc..

Once you have the WCF Service written try to invoke it from some tools like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) to make sure that you would not have problems when non.NET clients access them.

If you are on .NET 3.5  then have a look at this [link](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html).

Going ahead in .NET 4.5 you have a new option in built into the framework to generate a Flat wsdl. Look at this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/10/05/what-s-new-in-wcf-4-5-flat-wsdl-support.aspx).